# Play overlapping Audio

Tags: sound

I've imported two wav-Files and want to play them successively. Both last about 1 sec but I want to start the second while the first is still playing. I tried `AudioOverlay` but it didn't work. Is it possible at all?
Ma version 11

Comment: In the [documentation for `AudioOverlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioOverlay.html) there's an example that shows how to specify an offset for each sample, which I think is what you want. Overlay two audio signals using a specified offset: `AudioOverlay[{{a1, 0}, {a2, 0.5}}]`.

Comment: You may also be interested in [`AudioPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioPad.html)

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But what is the format of a1,a2 in the example? Not the wav, not SoundSample, ... I got nothing to work. Same with AudioPad.